# In jQuery UI 1.9 or higher, how to suppress restoring after size effect?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

It seems that jQuery UI 1.9 or higher restores to the original size after size effect. My sample code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mQCxY/

```
$(function () {
    $('.circle').click(function () {
        $(this).effect("size",
            { to: {width: 50,height: 50}, origin: ['bottom', 'right'] },
            1000, function () {
                $(this).css({'background': 'blue' });
        });
    });
});
```

Basically, if I choose jQuery UI 1.8.18 (under jQuery 1.7.2), then the shape will shrink to the right size and stay there. But later jQuery UI will restore the shape.

I also noticed that the "origin" options did not take effect for higher jQuery UI. For example, I used

```
origin: ['bottom', 'right']
```

Which had no effect for jQuery UI 1.9 or higher versions.

So how to suppress the 'restore' and make 'origin' effective in jQuery UI 1.8 or later?

Comment: Why do you use `effect` instead of `animate`? You should see this function as it sounds: as an effect. Lets bounce, rotate and fade elements with `effect`, but don't change them permanently. Therefore use `animate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a made a new function what will do what you need [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQCxY/31/)

i changed from `effect` to `animate` , and modifiyng css top+left to achive origin functionality,
note that default it goes to top-left.
ex.

origin => `['bottom']`  the same as `['bottom','left']`

origin => `['right']` the same as `['top','right']`
etc..

```
function size(object,to, origin, duration, callback){
    var leftResult = '+=0';
    var topResult = '+=0';
    if (origin != null && origin.length != 0){
        if ($.inArray('right', origin) >= 0){
            leftResult= '+='+to.width;
        }
        if ($.inArray('bottom', origin) >= 0){
            topResult= '+='+to.height;
        }
    }
    $(object).animate({
        height: to.height,
        width: to.width,
        left: leftResult,
        top: topResult
  }, duration, function() {
    if (typeof callback == "function") callback($(object));
  });
}
```

just add validation to arguments, or change the callback as you need.

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer. Why does this solve the problem?

Comment: This is the way i tried. I wonder if there is any option for doing this job. Also, how about the origin?

Comment: Whats about my comment above?

Comment: Slevin, your comment is valid and I am thinking to use animate instead. But I like to use something already there like the old jQuery UI size effect. But still don't understand why there is such a big difference in effect.

Comment: Cause `effect` does not match your need (or rather it's intended for a different purpose), but `animate` does :) And `animate` is already there, because you're using jQuery.

Comment: that's right, he just needed effect's 'origin' functionality, and i added it.

Comment: Thanks Eugen! Thought, I am still curious if there is any official notice about this change